# Android Dialog alert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  input.setText("");
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

  }
});
```

I am showing this dialog on click of a button on my screen. First time it shows alert perfetly, but when click again on the button for showing alert then it is giving error.
Please suggest me , what is the actual problem

Comment: what error is coming ? Upload logcat ..

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: In addition, how are you showing the dialog?  Are you using Activity.showDialog() or are you explicitly calling AlertDialog.show() inside of a button click event?  The code for this would be helpful.

Comment: It is giving error "Application has stopped working unexpectadely. Please try again"

Comment: I am using AlertDialog.show() method on button click event

Comment: Try by defining a `Context` and use instead of `this`

Comment: Works fine for me. PLEASE Google LogCat and how to use it in Eclipse & Android. We need to know what exceptions are happening and where. The code you have in the post works fine.

Comment: go to to add image and text you want to show in ur alert dialog box... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861216/1428123 and edit in ur java code like below http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861174/1428123

Answer (score 0):

For this You need to override onPrepareDialog() in addition to having the OnCreateDialog(). Because after the first you create the dialog, the next time it goes for onPrepareDialog().

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


adb.setView(alertDialogView);


adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");


adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);


adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);


        Toast.makeText(Tutoriel18_Android.this, et.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } });


adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        finish();
  } });
adb.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem yesterday. I solved it by creating the alert dialog everytime I wanted to show. Instead of showing it multiple times and only create it one time. That means that every time the button is clicked the AlertDialog will both be created and showed.

Use this method to create the alertDialog:

```
AlertDialog createAlertDialog() 
{
    Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setView(alertDialogView);
    adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");
    adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
        EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        Toast.makeText(Tutoriel18_Android.this, et.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    });
    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        } 
    });
    return adb.create();
}
```

And use this when you want the alert dialog to show:

```
createAlertDialog().show();
```